# Alternate definition limit

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, definition

The definition of the limit of a sequence is:

$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)\Leftrightarrow\forall\epsilon>0:\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\left(n>N\Rightarrow d_Y\left(f(n),L\right)<\epsilon\right)\,,$

for $f:\mathbb{N}\to Y$, $L\in Y$, and $d_Y$ a metric on $Y$, and the definition of the limit in a metric space is

$L=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)\Leftrightarrow\forall\epsilon>0:\exists \delta>0:\forall x\in X:\left(d_X(x,x_0)<\delta\Rightarrow d_Y\left(f(x),L\right)<\epsilon\right)\,,$

for $f:X\to Y$ and $d_X$ a metric on $X$.

**Question:** does a metric $d_X$ exist on $X=\mathbb{N}$ such that the first definition is a special case of the second definition?

**My thoughts:** Perhaps $d_\mathbb{N}(x,y)=\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right|$ would do, but $\infty\notin\mathbb{N}$, so I would have to define the metric on $\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$, but then $f$ also needs to be defined for $\infty$, which is normally not the case.

Comment: The problem is that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is a different kind of limiting process than $\lim_{x\to x_0}$.

Comment: @AlexR, do you mean that there maybe an even more general definition of a limit forwhich these two cases are special cases?

Comment: Well, the difference is as you already noticed, $\infty \notin \mathbb N$. You can define convergence of sequences first (by the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ definition) and use this for the $\lim_{x\to x_0}$ definition where $x_0$ need not necessarily be in the domain of $f$.

Comment: I thought since $\lim\limits_{x\to 2}f(x)$ is defined just well for $f:\left[0,2\right)\to Y$, that is without the $2$, perhaps it doesn't matter that $\infty$ is not in the domain of $f:\mathbb{N}\to Y$. However, I think the definition of the limit in metric spaces needs to be adjusted in the case $\infty\in X$.

Comment: You have an implicit completion of $[0,2)$ when applying the metric, since you compute $d_X(x,2)$ where $2\notin [0,2)$. You can do the same with the metric you proposed for the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ case.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is the following: you can define the metric in $\mathbb{N}\cup\infty$ as you suggest: $d(x,y)=|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$, $d(x,\infty)=|\frac{1}{x}|$. Suppose you have a function $f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow Y$. Then

**The function $f$ is extensible continuously to $\bar{f}:\mathbb{N}\cup\infty\longrightarrow Y$ if and only if the sequence related to $f$ has limit in the first sense, and in this case, $\bar{f}(\infty)=L$. Moreover, now the expression $\lim_{n\longrightarrow \infty}\bar{f}(n)=L$ is valid and is stated in the second sense (because we are using $\bar{f}$).**

Comment: I'm sorry but I find "The function $f$ is extensible to $\overline{f}:\mathbb{N}\cup\infty\to Y$ if and only if the sequence related to $f$ has limit in the first sense" very confusing. One can always extend a function right? Could you perhaps give the precise definition of the limit you are proposing?

Comment: Perhaps something like: $\forall f:X\to Y:\forall L\in Y:\forall x_0\in\overline{X}:L=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)\Leftrightarrow\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in X:d_{\overline{X}}(x,x_0)<\delta\rightarrow d_Y(f(x),L)<\epsilon$? So only changing the $d_X$ into $d_{\overline{X}}$?

Comment: I meant extensible continuously (sorry I did not say it; I'll edit the answer). If $\mathbb{N}\cup\infty$ has a metric, then not every extension is continuous. What do you mean by 'the limit you are proposing'? I use the two senses you give in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @carucel If $\infty$ is not added to the space, the metric $|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}|$ induces the usual topology (if you are not used to topology, just do not care about this comment). It may seem that making the numbers get closer and closer in the first space helps the images be close enough to converge in the second space, but this is not true. In this sense, no metric in $\mathbb{N}$ will work; you have to define a metric on $\mathbb{N}\cup\infty$.

Comment: So you mean to change the definition of a limit into: $\forall f:X\to Y:\forall L\in Y:\forall x_0\in\overline{X}:L=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)\Leftrightarrow\exists \overline{f}\text{ continuous extension }f\text{ on }\overline{X}:\forall\epsilon>0:\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in\overline{X}:d_{\overline{X}}(x,x_0)<\delta\rightarrow d_Y(\overline{f}(x),L)<\epsilon$? Isn't this definition equivalent to the one I gave in the second comment?

Comment: @carucel The problematic point is that $\overline{X}$ has sense only for a metric space _inside_ other metric space. If I have only defined $X$ with a metric, it has no sense to talk about $\overline{X}$. The additional points one wants to add have to be explicitely written. In our case, we have constructed a second space (with metric) and we have the inclussion $\mathbb{N}\subset\mathbb{N}\cup\infty$. And then, yes, $\infty\in\overline{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: $\overline{X}$ does make sense for $X$ a metric space right? There is no need for it to be inside another metric space. If we define $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $d$ as above, then $\overline{X}=\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{\infty\right\}$ right? Then both definitions I gave in the comments will do, right?

Comment: @carucel Strictly speaking (in the general topology sense) $\overline{X}$ does not make sense... for instance think in the interval $X=(0,1)$. One would say $\overline{X}=[0,1]$ because we are used to see $(0,1)$ _inside_ $\mathbb{R}$. But search in google pictures about the topologist's sine curve: the structure of $(0,1)$ in itself is the same, but we have a different inclussion, and now the adherence seems to require adding a complete interval.